# Change Snowflake Database Owner

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-quicksight, snowsql

We are trying to display data in a database that belongs to ACCOUNTADMIN role using AWS QuickSight. The problem is when we are trying to connect QuickSight to Snowflake, QuickSight automatically uses database that is in SYSADMIN role, there is no option where I can choose to display database that is in ACCOUNTADMIN role in QuickSight. Therefore, is there a SQL syntax that changes DSA database owner ACCOUNTADMIN to SYSADMIN including the tables, views, and schema in it as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [grant ownership](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-ownership.html) seem to be what you want, and thus

```
grant ownership on database dsa to role SYSADMIN;
```

should work.

I found that help page on the Snowflake Documentation site via the search `change ownership`

Comment: it works, just need to add "grant ownership on database dsa to role SYSADMIN revoke current grants;" thank you!

Comment: I would have thought you would still want prior roles to have grants.. but then again if ACCOUNTADMIN has to swap to SYSADMIN to interact with the table that's not a bad hint..